# NSArray vs. NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a core data stack with 2 entities: 'Client' and 'Car'. It is a one to may relationship. I have two tableViewControllers to display firstly the clients, and then once a client has been chosen a list of *that* clients cars.

I am currently using the following code fragment in my second tableViewController `viewDidLoad` method...

```
NSSet *cars = client.cars;
carsArray = [cars allObjects];
```

`carsArray` is a `NSArray` and is declared and synthesized in the second tableViewCotroller. If I try and make `carsArray` an `NSMutableArray` (so I can edit it later in the event a car is deleted) I get the following compiler warning...

`Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *' when passing argument 1 of 'setCarsArray:' from distinct Objective-C type`

Could someone explain to me why this works with a `NSArray` but not an `NSMutableArray` please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allObjects` method returns `NSArray *` and if you simply try to assign it to an `NSMutableArray` property you are not converting the object itself.

You need to use `+[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]` or a more generic method `-[NSObject mutableCopy]`:

```
[self setCarsArray:[[cars allObjects] mutableCopy]];
```

This will be the case for all mutable classes in Objective-C: to create a mutable object from immutable you'll have to explicitly call the conversion methods.